# API Rest Java EE erros: MUST be public scoped otherwise the method is ignored e No Persistence for EntityManager

Tags: java, rest, api

I am making an api for providers control but I have 2 errors when I try accessing the api methods:

**Warnings**

WARNING: The following warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:

WARNING: A sub-resource method, java.util.List br.com.sabrina.api.controller.ProviderController.list(), MUST be public scoped otherwise the method is ignored

WARNING: A sub-resource method, br.com.sabrina.api.model.ProviderModel br.com.sabrina.api.controller.ProviderController.search(int), MUST be public scoped otherwise the method is ignored

**Errors**

Jul 27, 2018 1:29:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/ApiRest] threw exception
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named provider

> About the warnings I did not got what could be wrong, and about the
>   persistence.xml I already have it created and configured correctly,
>   I do not know what the problem might be.

**Project structure**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Classes**

**ProviderController.java**

```
package br.com.sabrina.api.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import br.com.sabrina.api.model.ProviderModel;

@Path("/provider")
public class ProviderController {
    private JpaEntityManager JPAEM = new JpaEntityManager();
    private EntityManager objEM = JPAEM.getEntityManager();

    @GET
    @Path("/list")
    @Produces("application/json")
    List<ProviderModel> list() {
        try {
            String query = "SELECT c FROM ProviderModel c ";
            List<ProviderModel> providers = objEM.createQuery(query, ProviderModel.class).getResultList();
            objEM.close();
            return providers;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(500); 
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/search/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    ProviderModel search(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        try {
            ProviderModel provider = objEM.find(ProviderModel.class, id);
            objEM.close();
            return provider;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(500); 
        }
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/register")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response register(ProviderModel objProvider) {
        try {
            objEM.getTransaction().begin();
            objEM.persist(objProvider);
            objEM.getTransaction().commit();
            objEM.close();
            return Response.status(200).entity("Cadastro realizado!").build();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(500); 
        }
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/update")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response update(ProviderModel objProvider) {
        try {
            objEM.getTransaction().begin();
            objEM.persist(objProvider);
            objEM.getTransaction().commit();
            objEM.close();
            return Response.status(200).entity("Cadastro alterado!").build();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(500); 
        }
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/delete/{id}")
    public Response delete(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        try {
            ProviderModel objProvider = objEM.find(ProviderModel.class, id);
            objEM.getTransaction().begin();
            objEM.remove(objProvider);
            objEM.getTransaction().commit();
            objEM.close();
            return Response.status(200).entity("Cadastro excluido!").build();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(500); 
        }
    } 
}
```

**ProviderModel.java**

```
package br.com.sabrina.api.model;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity  //estrutura de mapeamento de objeto relacional
@Table(name="Provider")
public class ProviderModel {  
    //correspondente a tabela Provider do banco de dados
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int provider_id;

    @Column(name="name")
    String name;

    @Column(name="cpf_cnpj")
    String cpf_cnpj;

    @Column(name="rg")
    String rg;

    @Column(name="address")
    String adress;

    @Column(name="city")
    String city;

    @Column(name="email")
    String email;

    @Column(name="register_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    Date register_date;

    public int getId() {
        return provider_id;
    }

    public void setId(int provider_id) {
        this.provider_id = provider_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**JpaEntityManager.java**

```
package br.com.sabrina.api.controller;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class JpaEntityManager {
    private EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("provider");
    private EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }
}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <!-- unidade de persistencia com o nome provider -->
    <persistence-unit name="provider">
        <!-- Implementação do JPA, no nosso caso Hibernate -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <!-- Aqui são listadas todas as entidades -->
        <class>br.com.sabrina.api.model.ProviderModel</class>
        <properties>
            <!-- Propriedades JDBC -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/provider" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <!-- Configurações específicas do Hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ApiRest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Thanks

Comment: The list() and search() methods must be public. That's what the warnings tell you.

Comment: @JBNizet so what changes I have to do? my class ProviderController is public.

Comment: The **methods** must be public.

Comment: Where is the `persistence.xml` file located?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha WebContent/META-INF/persistence.xml

Comment: Try and put the META folder into the src folder

Comment: Also by default a new resource method is created for each request. This means that will keep on creating new EntityManagerFactorys. This is a very expensive object to create. You should only have one for the entire life of the application.